# Query Events from Multiple Google Calendars in Single Batch

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, gdata-api, gdata

Is there a way to query for events in multiple calendars (in the same Google account) in a single batch request?

I've been through the Google documentation [here](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_python.html#batch), but it hasn't really helped.

What I'm trying to do really is scan through a given user's calendars and get a list of events for each one.

An example in python/gdata would be amazing.

EDIT: Looks like [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/google-calendar-help-dataapi&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&parenturl=http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/community/forum.html#!searchin/google-calendar-help-dataapi/batch/google-calendar-help-dataapi/UI2hCu25Ibc/3pRQS6h1k4QJ) answers my question.  TL;DR not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long answer: The API does not allow you to fetch more than one calendar with a single request and it doesn't allow you to manipulate more than one calendar in a single request.

If this is really important to you (you're trying to reduce requests so I guess it's about performance), you could possible use the Google App Engine to create a function that would perform this work for you. I'm not sure you would see a big jump in performance though.